# custom android.intent.action.RINGTONE_PICKER

Tags: android, notifications

In addition to a list of notification sounds, I'd like to add a list of custom sounds i've bundled with my app, to be chosen with from a RingtonePreference (I want to make available some 30 second long notification sounds in addition to the short ones available by default). It seems to me the easiest way would be to extend android.intent.action.RINGTONE_PICKER to list a few extra ringtones, but I can't seem to find the source. How would I go about extending this intent? Is this a safe thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't extend an intent. You can use it in the manifest and show your own activity with a listView of which items can be selected.

An alternative would be to create your own dialog with items: "choose from OS...", "appSound1", "appSound2", ... . Here, the first item would raise the normal dialog of the android.intent.action.RINGTONE_PICKER intent.